# vim command to highlight text withing matching parenthesis

Tags: vim

I used `:set showmatch` and `:DoMatchParen` but that only highlights the matching parenthesis. Is there a way to make vim highlight all the code within the function (matching parenthesis)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Robbie is right but you can use `vib` too, which stands for "visual-select inner block". So you do not have to reach out for the Shift-Key.

See `:h ib` inside Vim.

Answer (score 0):

use `vi(` while in normal mode with the cursor between the parenthesis.

This puts you in `v`isual mode and selects `i`n the parens `(`)